# How to distribute oracle database

Tags: database, oracle11g

I want to distribute oracle database 11g on 3 servers but I don't know how to start.
I read some documents like :

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96521/ds_concepts.htm

and some others that are the same .
but I didn't find how to start.
I want a get start document about how to start distribute oracle , that contains :

1) how to install oracle for distribution

2) how to link them with some rules

3) how to query in a java application

Comment: What's your main motivation for a distributed setup? Is it to integrate several existing system? To achieve higher reliability? To achieve faster response time in different geographical locations? Higher overall throughput?

Comment: I want to integrate some existing system , there are some customers that use our system in different location , but a center branch want to query from their databases that are on other locations

Comment: If you are using 11g, then why do you read the manual for 9.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your comment, you want to integrate several existing system. In that case, the easiest approach are database links:

There is no special installation involved. Just add the remote databases to TNSNAMES.ORA so that they know how to connect to each other.

Then create a database link, e.g.:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK orlando
   CONNECT TO joe
   IDENTIFIED BY mysecret
   USING orcl33b;
```

Now you can query data (or insert or update):

```
SELECT a.name, b.total_amt
FROM person a
JOIN sales@orlando b
WHERE a.id = b.cust_id;
```

`sales@orlando` refers to the remote table `sales` in the remote `orlando` database.

There are different types of database links (regarding authentication, sharing and availability in other schema). You'll need to check which is best serves you.

Comment: thanks for your complete answer , may you link me to a complete tutorial for more details ?

Comment: I change tnsnames.ora and add needed information , I successfully create link , but when I run the query I get TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor error @Codo

Comment: @omidhaghighatgoo That indicates that the tnsnames isn't properly setup. Have you made the tns changes on the server side? Because that's where they are needed. If you can't figure it out, you should probably ask a specific question at http://dba.stackexchange.com/